# Installshield command line IsCmdBld.exe not modifying the Product version

Tags: command-line, command-line-arguments, installshield, installshield-2013

I'm using the following command inside a batch file to create a fresh version of installer from an Installshield project.

**The product version is hardcoded to 1.0.0 in the .ism file**

```
ISCmdBld.exe -p "%INST_SHIELD_FILE%" -y "%RELEASE_VERSION%"
```

where

- %INST_SHIELD_FILE% - contains the path for installshield project file
- %RELEASE_VERSION% - software release version, **for ex: 1.0.0**

Although, the Installshield project compiles successfully. The product version of package however remains unchanged.

For ex: If I run the command for next release version say **1.0.2**

```
ISCmdBld.exe -p "%INST_SHIELD_FILE%" -y "1.0.2"
```

The installer setup.exe package still reflects the old (**1.0.0**) product version.

Can anyone let me know how to modify the product version in the command line without actually modifying in the installshield project.

Should I use path variables to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution by myself. The trick was to override the value of a Custom Path Variable in the command line

Step 1.
 
Create a Path variable say ProductVersion with a Default value.
Step 2.
Assign the path variable to ProductVersion.
Step 3.
Follow steps mentioned [here](http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield22helplib/helplibrary/OverridingPathVar-Release.htm)
Step 4.

ISCmdBld.exe -p "%INST_SHIELD_FILE%" -l ISProductVersion="%RELEASE_VERSION%"

That's it. The project builds with the necessary product version being updated as I would require.